# Using \ character in textarea

Tags: javascript, string, textarea

This might be an stupid question for many of you, but I'm hitting a wall with the stupidest thing. 
I'm displaying code in a textarea field, but the code includes the character \, so it disappears in the code shown.
This is the exact line:

```
'return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")'+
```

And this is what is displayed:

```
return x.toString().replace(/B(?=(d{3})+(?!d))/g, ",")
```

I know the solution is easy, but I can't find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the `\` character is an escape character within strings in JavaScript.  If you want the character itself to show, you need to escape it with another one:  `\\`

So your code would need to be:

```
'return x.toString().replace(/\\B(?=(\\d{3})+(?!\\d))/g, ",")'+
```

Answer (score 0):

To display a literal \ you could just convert it to it's HTML entity values using a table like [this](http://www.freeformatter.com/html-entities.html)

For backslash you would want to type `&#92;`

If the code snippets you want to print are stored in a DB and fetched via PHP you could always run a htmlentities() on them before echo:ing them to your frontend to ensure characters like backslash are displayed properly.